# how to make the volume keys to show no effect on Audioplyer Sound

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, volume, alarm

I am working on an Alarm app and i used AVAudioPlayer to play the alarm Sound, I have a slider to adjust the audioPlayer Sound in my application settings.Now when the alarm is making any sound i dont want to reduce/increase the audioPlayer Sound through the volume Keys of Iphone/Ipad.

```
 //to set the slider value as player sound in my app
player.volume =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]floatForKey:@"Volume"];
```

can anybody please suggest me on how to make the volume keys to show no effect on player Sound when the alarm is playing sound.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should not change the default behavior of any device functionality. Apple won't approve the application as per my experience.

Comment: True that. It would also be rude to play an alarm without allowing the user the chance to silence it.

Comment: i don't think that apple will reject this type of functionality.I got some reference from http://fredandrandall.com/blog/?p=660 please check.